# Can't access database column in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, linq

I have both a table and a class in my system called `Operações`.

In this code:

```
var db = new ApplicationDbContext();
var model = db.Estruturas.Include(m => m.Produto).Include(m => m.Produto.Unidade);
var operacao = db.Operacoes;

foreach (var register in model)
{
    operação.
```

Typing `operação.` won't bring up intellisense and show any properties of the database table, or the class. How can I access them?

Comment: `operacao`, not `operação`. See also [Naming Guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/naming-guidelines). Names in c# are also case sensitive. It should go without saying that `ã` is not the same as `a`, they are not interchangeable in the name of a variable the same as A an a are not interchangeable in the name of a variable.

Answer (score 1):

operacao instead of operação. The name is different.

Also, it is a good practice not to use special characters like ç or ã